# How to add modifiers using python script and set parameters?

Tags: python, scripting, modifiers

I've found some code that could add a modifier but none can set parameters like *Octree*.

[image]

Comment: What modifier is this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can add a new modifier to an object with [`ObjectModifiers.new()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.ObjectModifiers.html#bpy.types.ObjectModifiers.new). If you store the result of calling [`ObjectModifiers.new()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.ObjectModifiers.html#bpy.types.ObjectModifiers.new) in a variable (in the example below I call it `modifier`) you then have access to all the properties of the new modifier:

```
import bpy

object = bpy.data.objects['Cube']

modifier = object.modifiers.new(name="Remesh", type='REMESH')
modifier.octree_depth = 5
```

You can see the `type` of modifier by hovering the mouse over the modifier in the *Add modifier* menu and you can see the name of the properties by hovering over the properties on the modifier.

Comment: how do you figure the parameters of each modifiers ?

Comment: @Phil If you have Python tooltips enabled you can just hover over the values in the interface.

Answer (score 0):

If you mouse over the field you should get a pop-up that show you a python expression for what the field refers to.  Since my knowledge of modifiers is far from encyclopedic I can not reproduce your situation in my blender.

Nevertheless, mouse-over is a standard technique for figuring out the python path to a field (although there are some data blocks whose path is complicated enough that you just end up with a ... in the middle)

Comment: well there is no hint on these fields, hence my post, but I used autocomplete in python console