# Python script to randomize modifiers and their values applied to an object

Tags: modifiers, objects

I’m completely new to blender and python, only having marginal experience with C+. I have a personal project where I’d like to apply randomized generative modifiers, with their values themselves using random values. Is this reasonable? I have a general idea that python can access blenders list of modifiers, assign variables to them and randomly select and apply from that set. As for values, having the script recognize which modifier has been “selected” and determine which values can be randomized. To begin I’d like to just apply one modifier, and then rerun the script to abstract the form further. Is this reasonable? As a newcomer to python it seems very flexible but perhaps this is too specific (python can actually manipulate values in this way)? Some recommendations or even rough sketches of such a script would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Adding modifiers or changing their parameters at random will likely not give you any useful output, constraining the allowed options is advisable. Nevertheless adding modifiers and adjusting the parameters is possible. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71569/how-to-add-modifiers-using-python-script-and-set-parameters

Comment: Got it, if I wanted to continue regardless is it possible to randomize the selected modifier? And consequently it’s value like the ones mentioned in the link? Essentially type=randomModifier and as an example, octree.depth(n), n being a random value.

Comment: And sorry, what constraints would be reasonable? I get that your saying certain inputs would be redundant.

Comment: While you can do what you're describing, it has the potential to go very wrong. You should therefore limit yourself to a subset of modifiers and a subset of their configurable properties. Ensure that you assign values from a sensible range to the properties. Otherwise you may not only create visually unappealing results, but very likely crash Blender. For instancing adding a subdivision modifier and setting the number of subdivisions to 10 is possible, but it will likely to consume more memory than you have.

Comment: Of course, that makes a lot of sense. It’s more experimental so I am hoping for absurdities. Again I am quite illiterate as far writing it goes. Any further suggestions? About the randomizing the library of modifiers for example?

Comment: Create a list of the modifiers you want, `import random` and then pick a random item from the list using `random.choice()`