# Add-on script problem

Tags: scripting, modifiers, add-on, error

Can anyone tell me why Blender thinks that object type Object does not have attribute modifier_add?

When you check what code Blender use when you manually add any modifier to object, it is this (in this case Bevel modifier):

```
bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='BEVEL')
```

So I can clearly see object type of Object does have such attribute, right?

But when I do that in my code it puts error message about non-existent attribute of modifier_add...this is my add-on code (it basically adds 3 different modifiers with specific values to any selected object, so that edges look little curved and smooth):

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "Add Beveling Modifiers To Selected Objects",
    "author": "me",
    "version": (1, 0),
    "blender": (2, 90, 1),
    "location": "View3D > Object > Add Beveling Modifiers To Selected",
    "description": "Add bunch of modifiers that will bevel and smooth edges in selected objects",
    "warning": "",
    "doc_url": "",
    "category": "Object",
}

import bpy
from bpy.types import (
    AddonPreferences,
    Operator,
    Panel,
    PropertyGroup,
)

class OBJECT_OT_addbevelingmodifierstoselected(Operator):
    bl_label = "Add Beveling Modifiers To Selected"
    bl_idname = "object.add_beveling_modifiers_to_selected"
    bl_description = "Add bunch of modifiers that will bevel and smooth edges in selected objects"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}
    
    # ONLY IF SOMETHING IS SELECTED AND IT IS A MESH
    @classmethod
    def poll (cls, context):
        return context.object.select_get() and context.object.type == 'MESH'
    
    def execute (self, context):
        
        # ===== ACTUAL ACTIONS START HERE ===== #
        for ob in bpy.context.selected_objects:
            bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = ob
            
            # BEVEL
            ob.modifier_add(type='BEVEL')
            bevel = ob.modifiers["Bevel"]
            bevel.affect = 'EDGES'
            bevel.offset_type = 'WIDTH'
            bevel.width = 0.02
            bevel.segments = 1
            bevel.limit_method = 'ANGLE'
            bevel.angle_limit = 1.48353
            bevel.profile_type = 'SUPERELLIPSE'
            bevel.profile = 1
            bevel.miter_outer = 'MITER_SHARP'
            bevel.miter_inner = 'MITER_SHARP'
            bevel.vmesh_method = 'ADJ'
            bevel.use_clamp_overlap = False
            bevel.loop_slide = True
            bevel.harden_normals = True
            bevel.mark_seam = True
            bevel.mark_sharp = True
            bevel.material = -1
            bevel.face_strength_mode = 'FSTR_NONE'
            
            # WEIGHTED NORMAL
            ob.modifier_add(type='WEIGHTED_NORMAL')
            weightednormal = ob.modifiers["WeightedNormal"]
            weightednormal.mode = 'FACE_AREA_WITH_ANGLE'
            weightednormal.weight = 20
            weightednormal.thresh = 0.01
            weightednormal.keep_sharp = True
            weightednormal.face_influence = False
            weightednormal.vertex_group = ""
            
            # SUBDIVISION
            ob.modifier_add(type='SUBSURF')
            subdivision = ob.modifiers["Subdivision"]
            subdivision.subdivision_type = 'CATMULL_CLARK'
            subdivision.levels = 1
            subdivision.render_levels = 1
            subdivision.show_only_control_edges = True
            subdivision.quality = 1
            subdivision.uv_smooth = 'PRESERVE_CORNERS'
            subdivision.use_creases = True
            subdivision.use_custom_normals = False

        # ===== ACTUAL ACTIONS END HERE ===== #
        
        return {'FINISHED'}
    
def menu_func_addbevelingmodifiers (self, context):
    self.layout.operator(OBJECT_OT_addbevelingmodifierstoselected.bl_idname)

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(OBJECT_OT_addbevelingmodifierstoselected)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_object.append(menu_func_addbevelingmodifiers)
    
def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(OBJECT_OT_addbevelingmodifierstoselected)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_object.remove(menu_func_addbevelingmodifiers)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: It doesn't think it, it knows that `bpy.types.Object`` doesn't have a `modifier_add` property. You are mixing apples and oranges, or in this case objects and operators.

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71569/how-to-add-modifiers-using-python-script-and-set-parameters

Comment: OK, but can you then make some example what part, or better said how the wrong part should look? You see, I am newbie and basically re-using my other addon script that did work (I post it somewhere around it here too before), thus I thought it would work if I only replace the "working part" itself

Comment: yes I know that - thanks, but I have no clue how to make it in for loop for every selected object, therefore I thought I am doing the right thing which in turns seems to be not right

Comment: Go to console `print(bpy.ops.object)` vs `print(C.object)`  And if you know it, do it.

Comment: actually, what I was expecting you to write was which part in the for loop should be changed so that the ob variable would represent actually selected active object of the all selected objects so that I could apply those modifiers to + BTW I am on PortableApps.com's Blender Portable and here output to System Console does not work at all

Comment: nevermind, I made it already, thanx