# Set a projector at UVProjection modifier (script)

Tags: python, scripting, modifiers, uv, camera

I am trying to create a script that involves the creation and setup of a [UV Project modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/modify/uv_project.html). When it comes to set the *UV Map* of the projector, there is no problem at all:

```
import bpy

bpy.data.objects['piece'].select_set(True)
bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='UV_PROJECT')
bpy.context.object.modifiers["UVProject"].uv_layer = "UVMap"
```

But when I'm trying to set the projector object, I find no way to do it, as "projectors" property seems to be *read-only*:

https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.UVProjectModifier.html?highlight=projection%20modifier

**Q:** Am I missing something or precisely that property is just not scriptable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to [How to add modifiers using python script and set parameters?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/71569/31447), the recommended way is to add a new modifier to an object using [`ObjectModifiers.new()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.ObjectModifiers.html#bpy.types.ObjectModifiers.new) which returns the reference to the modifier and allows to assign whatever you like:

```
import bpy

# Get the object in context
obj = bpy.context.object

# Add the modifier to the object in context
modifier = obj.modifiers.new(name="project", type='UV_PROJECT')

# Properties
modifier.uv_layer = "UVMap"
modifier.projector_count = 10

for p in modifier.projectors:
    p.object = bpy.context.scene.camera
```

[projectors](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.UVProjectModifier.html?highlight=projection%20modifier#bpy.types.UVProjectModifier.projectors) property is of type `bpy_prop_collection`, which is essentially a list of object references. In order to assign an object to each *Object* property of the modifier, you would have to assign an object reference like `bpy.context.scene.camera`.

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked just fine and did what I was expecting. My strategy consisted of seeing the info window and try to copy/paste instructions into a script in order to automatize them, but it seems it is not working like this. Best regards

Comment: Glad it helps @JaimeFinat